# How to view Stored Procedures in Squirrel

Tags: database, squirrel-sql

Would like to know if one can view stored proc is Squirrel. Is there a plugin for this?

Comment: Did you try SQuirreL SQL Client Version 3.7?

Answer (score 2):

What version of SQuirreL are you working on ?..

I have 3.2.1 and all I need to do is click on "Objects" tab, expand your connection, look for your database, expand it, and then look for "Procedure" then click on the procedure you want, and then click on the "Source" tab

Comment: Do you have a plugin for that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install your correspondent database plugin. In case of `sqlserver`, you can install it with squirrel-sql installation by checking `Microsoft SQL-Server Plugin` as per below:

[image: sqlserver plugin].

So once installed, you can:

- Right click on the stored procedure in the left menu,
- Select **sql server** from the drop down menu,
- Then select **script procedure** from the sub-menu

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get Stored Procedures source code on Ingres database:

```
select
    procedure_name, text_sequence, text_segment
from
    iiprocedures
where
    procedure_name = 'sp_name_goes_here'
order by
    text_sequence
```

Aloha!

Answer (score 0):

Using SQuirreL 3.5.2, I knew there should be Procedures in our database but they were not showing by default. I right-clicked the Procedures and chose "Refresh Item" to get them to show. Must not be loaded by default so that can be misleading.